# How do I override methods of a view from Layout?

Tags: java, android, view, overriding

I am wondering how extend a `View` class that is right inside my layout from my code.
I have seen different examples where we say for example:

```
listView = new ListView(this){
   //Override some methods here
 }
```

Now what if i already have the `ListView` in my layout and i still want to override something. the only way i can reference the `ListView` from inside my layout is for example:

```
listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylistView);
```

So from this example how do I override a method of the list view.
Please I am just an average android programmer. Please enlighten me.

Comment: Profile says "a specialist in Android Development", question says "just an average android programmer"... Funny stuff.

Comment: I added that because I studied android programming not full Java programming and the question seems related to general Java syntax

Answer (score 6):

You either have to programmatically build your layout (which is tedious and annoying most of the time), or subclass ListView in a named class and add that to your layout. Here's what the second option looks like:

```
public class MyListView extends ListView {

    public MyListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public MyListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    // override other methods here
}
```

in your layout file, use

```
<com.your.package.MyListView
    android:layout_width="..."
    android:layout_width="..."
    ... />
```

Comment: I know this method before but does that mean that what I want here is not possible?

Comment: I don't recommend the approach in your original question. This is by far much cleaner to anyone who has to read your code later. The method you propose involves no listview in the layout, an anonymous inner class in your activity, and programmatically adding that listview to the layout somewhere.